# 403 Forbidden Nginx on Ubuntu error only on some pages / directories

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, nginx

Been struggling with this problem for some days now, and can't seem to find a solution.

I made a server on my Raspberry PI with Ubuntu server and NGINX.
My goal is to host multiple webpages on the server, mainly using wordpress.

Subdomain is just a madeup domain.
The problem that I dont understand occurs when I want to visit my domain, [www.subdomain.com](http://www.subdomain.com).
The domain itself gives me a 403 Forbidden error - but if I visit [www.subdomain.com/wordpress](http://www.subdomain.com/wordpress) it automatically sends me to [www.subdomain.com/wp-admin/installation.php](http://www.subdomain.com/wp-admin/installation.php) as wanted, and I can create my wordpress page.
The same occurs when I log in to my new Wordpress installation and it refers me to [www.subdomain.com/wp-admin/](http://www.subdomain.com/wp-admin/), again I get an 403 Forbidden Error, but if manually enters [www.subdomain.com/wp-admin/index.php](http://www.subdomain.com/wp-admin/index.php) it all works fine.

**STEP BY STEP**

- I made a subdomain /var/www/subdomain.com.
- Installed WordPress /var/www/subdomain.com/wordpress.
- Configured wp-config.

```
define( 'DB_NAME', 'wp_subdomain' );
/** Database username `*`/
define( 'DB_USER', 'user_subdomain' );
/`*`* Database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password' );

define('AUTH_KEY',         '&jD{O Fid.qm7Ujf8JFO~nL84% cMRcW&^+`*`F,;sQ$Pv6aS0V?0keq5(/]ApGg#'); 
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'r^Z6)Hb(T9OJ= J{tZ4D?AYp+9R>b.YBu>{2{k|<7lX3Insw:#i|4jG|=Ih)Z- X'); 
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'Y<L-SM%}#kO=f+lrx$V}@iePw9HbG7CwFr`*`X-eHz|z&T/Xi+Nb6S>Mlt=OT81B/');
define('NONCE_KEY',        '.,ab^j2KfE4Ltv_]e=M<}R!]Df!.jrrE,g1|5>@6_om.#S/#L-L^,7Kdk)pnT>}U');`
`define('AUTH_SALT',        '@NY5>IC,lX$2-#t3<(:jw.Ri!4V0bNVY/-I*;EJeX_ro5I9+D45v0=O *q[|Z8o ');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'V(mG+uH6u3MWc|Uxxi{w2-p|*+Wc}OpPS5-[P.%)Gn+Cpn_MfN_2V#7jV?g]');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'r!f+Q&&FJk=V(UMIBxA=}ZB4++2:8xe3<sE/;QpXEHT%^z~m.{>]6{bV#q>N#O%'); define('NONCE_SALT',       'g7zUw}Rv+9&3.A&mp1GJ[4[;;T.{pE2aA!o:]]}k(#KgP@uISs~62~G3BQZveVK');
```

Configured /etc/nginx/sites-available/subdomain.com.conf & copied it to sites-enabled.
Both of them include:

```
upstream subdomain-php-handler {
    server unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.com www.subdomain.com;
    root /var/www/subdomain.com/wordpress;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ .php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass subdomain-php-handler;
    }
}
```

- Setup database and granted permission with mysql mariadb.
  Used mysql commands:

```
create database wp_subdomain default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
grant all on wp_subdomain.* to 'user_subdomain'@'localhost' identified by 'password';
flush privileges;
```

at last

```
nginx -t (all was fine)
systemctl restart nginx
```

- All servers are connected and works.

Nginx error:

```
root@ubuntu:/# tail -20 /var/log/nginx/error.log`
6890#6890: *272 directory index of "/var/www/subdomain/wordpress/" is forbidden, client: 86.52.42.195, server: subdomain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "subdomain.com"

10246#10246: *13 directory index of "/var/www/subdomain.com/wordpress/wp-content/" is forbidden, client: 86.52.42.195, server: subdomain.com, request: "GET /wp-content/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www.subdomain.com"
```

5-6 more 10246#10246 errors

```
10248#10248: *124 directory index of "/var/www/subdomain.com/wordpress/" is forbidden, client: 89.104.110.115, server: subdomain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "subdomain.com"
```

I tried to `chmod 755 /path/to/directory` to all my directories inside.

Thanks you so much in advance.
Does anyone have an idea? or what i should look into, to make this work?

Comment: What does this question have to do with SQL Server?

Comment: I  regards to the formatted, have a read of [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), which explains how markdown works.

Comment: The error message does not match the `server` block in your question. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files and check that the `server` block appears the same as the one posted in your question.